# Debug a makefile with pkgconfig

Tags: c++, makefile, gstreamer

.
Novice to makefile. I am trying out the Gstreamer library. Need to issue a command to the CLI as

```
'gcc basic-tutorial-1.c -o basic-tutorial-1 `pkg-config --cflags --libs gstreamer-1.0`
```

I am trying to write a make file to simplify things

And my makefile is as follows

```
CC        = gcc
CFLAGS    =  `pkg-config --cflags gstreamer-1.0`
LDFLAGS    =  `pkg-config --libs gstreamer-1.0`
CLIBS     = `pkg-config --libs gstreamer-1.0`

SOURCE    = basic-tutorial-1.c
TARGET    = demo

video : $(TARGET).o
    $(CC) $(LDFLAGS) -o $(TARGET).o

$(TARGET).o : $(SOURCE)
    $(CC) $(CFLAGS) -c $(SOURCE) 

clean:
    rm -f $(TARGET) $(OBJECTS)
```

It gives me an error message

```
make: Entering directory '/home/test/VSCode/C++/Gstreamer'
gcc `pkg-config --cflags gstreamer-1.0` -c basic-tutorial-1.c 
gcc `pkg-config --libs gstreamer-1.0` -o demo.o
/usr/lib/gcc/x86_64-linux-gnu/7/../../../x86_64-linux-gnu/Scrt1.o: In function `_start':
(.text+0x20): undefined reference to `main'
collect2: error: ld returned 1 exit status
makefile:14: recipe for target 'video' failed
make: *** [video] Error 1
make: Leaving directory '/home/test/VSCode/C++/Gstreamer'
```

What should i do next?

Thanks

Comment: Show the source code being compiled. It seems it doesn't have an `int main()`, or said function is in another translation unit (cpp file) that you don't compile.

Comment: Why is this tagged c++?  If you are using C++, don't use `CC`, use `CXX` and `CXXFLAGS`.  This looks like C.

Comment: @William Pursell. you are right

Comment: @underscore_d the source file has a int main(). It was from one of the tutorial under gstreamer site

Answer (score 1):

Check if you have the main() function in the source files being compiled

Answer (score 1):

For [GNU make](https://www.gnu.org/software/make/),

```
 CFLAGS    =  `pkg-config --cflags gstreamer-1.0`
```

is wrong, and you should code:

```
 CFLAGS = $(shell pkg-config --cflags gstreamer-1.0) -Wall -Wextra -g
```

Read the documentation of GNU make and try `make -p`

Answer (score 1):

This recipe is incomplete:

```
video : $(TARGET).o
    $(CC) $(LDFLAGS) -o $(TARGET).o
```

What are you compiling?  If $(TARGET).o is a dependency, why is it listed as the output of $(CC)?  Not sure what you really want here, but perhaps:

```
$(CC) $(TARGET).o -o video $(LDFLAGS)
```